# Why did Virgil hide in the The Glowing Sea?

Tags: fallout-4

Why did Virgil hide in the The Glowing Sea when coursers are unaffected by radiation anyway?

Comment: Can you edit the question title so as to not spoil the game? Thanks.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to change the question as to not spoil the game but also still ask that specific question. Anything specific you think it should be changed too?

Comment: @Crystalwolf I have a suggested edit that hasn't been approved yet. Changed the title to Why did Virigl hide in the Glowing Sea?, and just copied the old title down to the body. Players wouldn't know who Virgil is or where the Glowing Sea is, so it seems fine to me.

Comment: That's not true, gen 3 synths are affected by radiation, which is what coursers are

Answer (score 8):

Virgil believed, correctly, that Kellog would be sent after him.

Kellog is not immune to radiation.

Comment: Is Kellog not immune to radiation though? He did eventually become part Synth himself and even had his own Synths at his disposal and control.

Comment: @Crystalwolf I suppose it's theoretically possible, but I don't have any reason to think that a couple implants would grant him radiation immunity. Are we even certain that coursers are immune to radiation? They're bio-engineered, unlike Nick.

Comment: That's a good question on whether they are immune themselves however it kind of becomes irrelevant when they are considered disposable and also the fact that the Children of Atom seem to be living fine in the radiated lands okay.

Comment: @DCShannon yeah, you're right - my apologies, I've removed my comment :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on institute main questline, synths can only be sent to areas without an em(electromagnetic) field in place. In physics and chem, radiation is a rich field of charged particles and creates own em field.

Comment: Which synths? Nick explicitly says he's unaffected by radiation.

Answer (score 1):

Virgil hid in the glowing sea, hoping that radiation would cover up his tracks.

Comment: Do you think you could expand on it a bit? What source do you have for this reasoning?